# django-mongodb-engine Where is GridFSField Model Field

Tags: python, django, mongodb, blob, gridfs

I'm using django-mongodb-engine for a project I'm working on and the documentation advises users to use the GridFS storage system for storing blobs as opposed to using the filesystem method. Obviously, this is one reason why we choose to use mongodb in the first place. One issue though, the documentation is *sparse* to say the least. In the [docs](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/gridfs.html#model-field) they mention to use the GridFSField as your blob model field. One problem... where is the GridFSField?

```
class Better(models.Model):
    blob = GridFSField()
```

iPython/Django shell:

```
from django_mongodb_engine.storage import GridFSStorage

#... define the class/exec

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in Better()
      1 class Better(models.Model):
----> 2         blob = GridFSField()
      3

NameError: name 'GridFSField' is not defined
```

Um, okay Django! Where is it defined then?!

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a specific answer to your question as that answer is going to most likely be about your setup configuration. But as you seem to be going through documentation examples and therefore evaluating I thought it would be worthwhile to provide some points on using [**GridFS**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/).

The intention of [**GridFS**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) is not to be a way of storing "blobs" or replacing usage of the "filesystem method" as you (or the ODM documentation) are stating. Yes it can be used that way, but the sole reason for it's existence is to overcome the 16MB [limitation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) MongoDB has on BSON document storage.

There is a common misconception that GridFS is a "feature" of MongoDB, yet it is actually a **specification** implemented on the **driver** side, for dealing with **chunking** large document content. There is no **magic** that occurs on the server side **at all**, as far as internal operations to MongoDB are concerned, this is just another BSON document with fields and data.

What the driver implementation is doing is breaking the content up into **smaller chunks** and distributing the content over several documents in a collection. Likewise when reading the content, there are methods provided to *follow* and *fetch* the various documents that make up the total content. In a nutshell, **reading** and **writing** using the GridFS methods results in **multiple** calls over the wire to MongoDB.

With that in mind, if your **content** is actually going to always be a size **under 16MB** then you are probably better off just using your **encoded** binary data within a single document, as updates will be atomic and the result will be faster reads from a single read operation per document.

So if you **must** have documents over 16MB in size, then use GridFS. If not just encode the content into a normal document field as that is all GridFS is doing anyway.

For more information, please read the FAQ:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#when-should-i-use-gridfs

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide that feedback. As you surmised, my data will be under the 16MB limitation, and therefore it's best that I implement a solution along your suggestion. However, I would still like to know how to implement the GridFS solution for future reference. But again, thanks for the info... This is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can find GridFSField under django_mongodb_engine.fields

i.e.

```
from django_mongodb_engine.fields import GridFSField
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):
    blob = GridFSField()
```